# Почему не развёртывается сервер?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер

И в дополнение к моему прошлому вопросу(уж не серчайте, первый раз вообще пытаюсь сервак у себя развернуть и использовать `python` как серверный язык)...

Нашёл эту [статью](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/118460/). Тут сказано что можно сервер развернуть так: `python -m CGIHTTPServer`

Но, к сожалению, у меня выдаёт ошибку что якобы нет такого модуля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И такой вопрос, а чтоже нужно чтобы сервак развернуть? -_-

Comment: Рекомендую нормальный сервер: apache. Или nginix.

Comment: Такс.... Дорогой, @VictorVosMottor, можете подсказать профану как их развернуть и будут ли они исполнять python-скрипты? -_-

Comment: У тебя винда или Linux?

Comment: А винда (по скриншоту понял).

Comment: https://editrocket.com/articles/python_apache_windows.html

Comment: И то и другое есть) Хорошо, спасибо, буду разбираться)

Comment: Тогда бери Linux. Нa нем лучше развертывется ;)

Comment: Обычно веб-приложения на питоне это `django` или `flask`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, ну, тут главное слово "обычно", а я вот хочу танцев с бубнами XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хочется использовать именно [CGIHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html). То в его документации стоит обратить внимание:

> The CGIHTTPServer module has been merged into http.server in Python 3.
> The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your
> sources to Python 3.

Сервер влили в `http.server`... куда влили? Давайте посмотрим что за [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).

Находим информацию, что тут в третьей версии языка все разнообразные виды серверов объединили в один класс, а для разных случаев жизни реализовали специальные обработчики (Handlers) и нас интересует [CGIHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler) прямо в конце списка.

Активировать этот обработчик можно вот так:

`python -m http.server --cgi 8000`

И получится CGI-сервер на 8000 порту.